# Visual Studio 2019 shows an empty solution after creating a .NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, csproj, solution

When I create a new .NET Core project in Visual Studio 2019, it shows only the solution file.  Other files are not showing and also I am not able to debug or the project.

[image: An empty solution node shown in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2019]

Comment: Right-click the `Solution 'araf'` node and select `Open Folder in File Explorer`.  Do you see your project files in either that directory or a subdirectory?  If so, you can try right-clicking the solution node and selecting `Add` → `Existing Project...` to add it to the solution.  If not, use `Add` → `New Project...` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I've also run into this problem and after two days of searching forums and reading .NET documentations, I finally managed to find the solution.

The problem is that Visual Studio cannot find the proper SDK version. There might be a few reasons for this, but first of all, check if you have any SDK installed:

1. Open the Command Prompt:

   *Start Menu > Visual Studio 2019 > Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2019*
2. Run the command: `dotnet --info`

#### Case 1:

The `.NET SDKs installed:` section says that you have no SDKs installed.

-OR-

A .NET SDK is installed but not for the right architecture (this was my case), meaning that you had installed x86 version instead of x64.

**Solution:**
Uninstall ***all*** versions of .NET Core  SDKs and Runtimes, then download and install the latest **x64** SDK and Runtime version from [Microsoft's webpage](https://aka.ms/dotnet-download).

#### Case 2:

A .NET SDK is installed but the referenced SDK version in the current project's `.csproj` file does not match the installed version nor the one specified in the `global.json` (if exists).

**Solution:** Edit the `.csproj` file, so that the SDK versions match.
If you have or need a `global.json` file, make sure you set its content properly. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x).

### Finally

Don't forget to open Visual Studio, create a new e.g. Console Application and see if the Solution's files appear in the Solution Explorer window (they should). Note that existing projects may still not be working properly because their `.csproj` file might have wrong SDK reference - if so, you have to fix them manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue in newer versions of Visual Studio as well with .NET 5 and .NET 6. There is a bug where Visual Studio can't find the installed SDK. Here is my suggested fix:

1. Go to Settings/Apps and Features and check the bitness of your installed .NET SDK.
2. Edit the PATH environment variable, and make sure the path to dotnet that matches the bitness of your installed SDK is set **before** the other one (or remove the other one completely):

   - for a 32-bit SDK: `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\`
   - for a 64-bit SDK: `C:\Program Files\dotnet\`
3. Restart Visual Studio (if you are using some kind of launcher, restart that launcher as well, since environment variables are inherited).

You can test if this works correctly by opening a command prompt and typing:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

The list should not be empty.